# Is there a local "firewall" to block by "X-Forwarded-For" IPs behind the reverse proxies?

Tags: firewall, x-forwarded-for

The situation is quite typical. I'm using CentOS + Apache(s) behind a Load-balancer for the WebSites.

---

At this point, let's assume i don't have any access to the Load-balancer (or) let's forget about that one.

---

Currently i'm using `.htaccess` to BLOCK the IPs because the native `iptables` is not able to block the `X-Forwarded-For` kind of IP addresses (as far as i understand).

My current approach works anyway. But this still allows my Apache(s) to be hit, at least.

Is there a `firewall` *(like: `iptables`)* which can block the `X-Forwarded-For` IP/connections as well?

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, firewalls like iptables work at the tcp layer. To look at the x-forwarded-for http header you need to accept the connection and accept at least the request headers from the client before you can evaluate the x-forwarded-for IP.

By far the best place to do the blocking is on load balancer itself before the request gets passed to apache, most load balancers will have this functionality.